# how to use pandas .query('_merge == left_only ') in pyspark

Tags: join, pyspark, databricks

I am new to pySpark and trying to join 2 DFs lets say A an B. I want to use .query('_merge == left_only ') in order to achieve my result. How can mirror same?

I tried removing null values from the result set of :
Left join DF 'A' with (Result set of inner join of 2 DFs A,B) .